# How to use Java DirContext to search for users with down-level logon name (NETBIOS\sAMAccountName)

Tags: java, authentication, active-directory, ldap, jndi

I am using javax.naming.directory.DirContext to connect with Microsoft AD. I can authenticate a user by performing bind using SECURITY_PRINCIPAL as NETBIOS\sAMAccountName, but post this, I need this user's attributes from AD. I am not able to figure out how to do this. If I should use DirContext.search, or DirContext.GetAttributes, what search filter or name shall be provided? I can't simply use sAMAccountName as there may be many users with same sAMAccountName.

Answer (score 0):

We have some [JNDI Examples](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/dba1d74d172f/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/?at=master) on how to Generically perform several JNDI functions.

The [BasicAdminSearchBind.java](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/dba1d74d172f9a3f13fc375f6d17370b6da91adf/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/BasicAdminSearchBind.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) is probably a good place to start.

The [ADConnection.java](https://bitbucket.org/jwilleke/examples/src/dba1d74d172f9a3f13fc375f6d17370b6da91adf/Examples-JNDI/src/com/willeke/samples/ldap/jndi/ADConnection.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) specific to Microsoft Active Directory.

**NOTE: These are examples -- Use at your own risk!**

-jim